# list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, list, merge, indexing

i have 2 types of lists: names, and scores and I'm trying to combine the scores so that all of the scores are combined into an existing list

I keep getting the "list indices must be integers, not str" error

```
name1= [jim, bob, john, smith]

score1= [4,7,3,11]

name2= [bob, cahterine, jim, will, lucy]

score2= [6,12,7,1,4]
```

I want the result to be:

```
name1 = [jim, bob, john, smith, catherine, will, lucy]

score2 = [11, 13 ,3 ,11 ,12 ,1 ,4]


def merge(name1,score1, name2,score2):

     for i in name2:
        if i in name1:
           indexed= name1.index(i)
           score2[i] =score1[int(indexed)]+score2[i]
        if i not in name1:
           name1.append(i)
           score1.append(score2[(name1.index(i))])
```

Comment: Why don't you merge them by simply: `name1 = name1 + name2` and `score2 = score1 + score2`?

Comment: icanc: OP wants the scores combined by name. That is, the resulting list should only have one entry for each name, and a score corresponding to the sum of scores associated with that name in the input lists.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to consider placing such data in [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module. For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from collections import Counter

name1 = ["jim", "bob", "john", "smith"]
score1 = [4,7,3,11]
name2 = ["bob", "cahterine", "jim", "will", "lucy"]
score2 = [6,12,7,1,4]

first_set = dict(zip(name1, score1))
second_set = dict(zip(name2, score2))

print Counter(first_set) + Counter(second_set)
```

This prints the following:

```
Counter({'bob': 13, 'cahterine': 12, 'jim': 11, 'smith': 11, 'lucy': 4, 'john': 3, 'will': 1})
```

Also, look at [Karl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15260748/1062948). It simplifies this even more.

Comment: +1 for good data structure choice, beating me to the punch by a couple minutes.

Comment: You don't need the intermediate dict, just do `Counter(zip(name1, score1))` etc.

Comment: @gnibbler Yes but you would need `Counter(dict(zip(name1, score1)))`. I just wanted to show the steps to the OP so it would be easier to follow. You can simplify this whole thing a lot more, of course, as in Karl's answer.

Answer (score 9):

You have scores that are conceptually **associated with** names. This tells you that you're using the wrong data structure. In particular, the numbers represent scores that you're going to be adding up, or more to the point, *counting* up.

Python has a built-in tool for this.

```
from collections import Counter

results_1 = Counter(jim = 4, bob = 7, john = 3, smith = 11)
results_2 = Counter(bob = 6, catherine = 12, jim = 7, will = 1, lucy = 4)

results_1 + results_2 # yes, it's really this easy.
```

As for your error message, it means exactly what it says, and @BryanOakley already explained it thoroughly. But I need to point out that *in programming, you must be precise, and consistent, and constantly pay attention to detail*. Good habits avoid these errors because you are constantly thinking about exactly what you are doing and *exactly what it means*. Style conventions help, too:

- Name your iterator after the thing that it actually contains. Since, in Python, iterating over a list *actually gives you items from the list* (not integer indices), use a name that suggests an actual list item, and not something bland like `i`.
- Name your lists and other containers with a plural name, so that your code naturally describes what's going on. Thus, write things like `for name in names:`.

But I mention "attention to detail" because

- When you are posting your code, don't type it out; copy and paste so that we can see exactly what you have.
- Spelling counts. Typos hurt (`cahterine`).
- Strings have quotes around them. Do not get strings confused with variable names.

Answer (score 5):

Trust in the error message: it is telling you exactly what the problem is. When you do `score2[i]`, ask yourself "what is i?"

In this context, i is an element of name2. Even though your example code shows it as `[bob, cahterine, jim, will, lucy]`, I'm guessing those are strings.

Answer (score 0):

i got this to work but i don't know if that is what you are looking for?

```
name1= ['jim', 'bob', 'john', 'smith']
name2= ['bob', 'cahterine', 'jim', 'will', 'lucy']
score1= [4,7,3,11]
score2= [6,12,7,1,4]
def merge (name1,score1, name2,score2):
    for x in range(0,len(name1)):
        name2.append(name1[x])
    for x in range(0,len(score1)):
        score2.append(score1[x])
    print name2
    print score2
merge(name1,score1, name2,score2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(index, name):
    score2[index] += score1[name1.index(name)]


name1= ["jim", "bob", "john", "smith"]
score1= [4,7,3,11]
name2= ["bob", "cahterine", "jim", "will", "lucy"]
score2= [6,12,7,1,4]

[sum(index, _name) for index, _name in enumerate(name2) if _name in name1 and _name in name2]
```

you can use list comprehensions